# adding namespace attribute to non-root elements using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Reading here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp it says

"Namespaces can be declared in the elements where they are used or in the XML root element:"

I'm using JAXB to marshall java classes to xml and require namesnames to be listed on a child element. It is required as I need to create non-standard xml. :(

I would like my xml to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rowdata xmlns="https://place.net/schema/docdatarow"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://place.net/schema/docdatarow  https://place.net/schema/docdatarow">
 <First_Name>A</First_Name>
<Last_Name>Russell</Last_Name>
<Profile_Id>transcript</Profile_Id>
<Doc_Xml_Data>
<data xsi:schemaLocation="https://place.net/schema/2014/03/20 https://place.net/schema/2014/03/20" xmlns="https://place.net/schema/2014/03/20" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<OverallSummary>
    <Heading>SUCCESSFUL COMPLETION</Heading>
    <Qualification>BA (Hons</Qualification>
    <ClassOfResult>2.1</ClassOfResult>
</OverallSummary>
</data>
</Doc_Xml_Data>
</rowdata>
```

I can't seem to set a xmlns against this child element using Annotations or package-info.java or anything else JAXB supported. They always end up in the root element.

Other than something messy like 2 separate marshalls and taking the results of  the inner marshall and setting this as a string of xml in the outer object, is it possible cleanly?

Cheers

n99

Comment: There is no such thing as "non-standard XML". Either it is XML according to the w3c spec, or it is not. - And what is "namesnames"? - Can you provide a sample XML document showing what you're after?

Comment: Are all the jaxb classes in the same package?

Comment: have added example - cheers

Comment: rowdata and data are in their own packages